# How does a neutral allele change relative to a nearby allele under selection?

Tags: genetics, genetic-linkage, crossover

Suppose I'm looking at a gene being selected against (A) that's decreasing at a rate ($\Delta$P). If there's a nearby allele that is neutral (B) am I correct to assume that B will decrease with A at a rate of $\Delta$P*cM?

So for instance, if A and B are .5 cM from each other and A decreases from .8 to .4, will B decrease from .8 to .6 because there is only a 50% crossover rate between the two?

Comment: Depends if your trait is dominant, recessive or additive. You should talk entirely in terms of alleles and not as genes as you have to consider the heterozygote case. Your calculation would be correct for a dominant allele with deleterious effects but not necessarily for a recessive or additive trait.